# Remove method for a linked list. Insert method is untraditional and runs on theta(1) time

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Hello all so I have a linked list here and I have to make a remove method that works properly. For example if I call remove(0) it should delete the first thing that was entered in the list and so on and so forth. This is a little bit different than most linked lists because usually the head node is at the 0ith place however in this case the head is at the end of the list. So my code so far works pretty good however I am unable to delete the head node or the last item in my list. Also if my list only has one element in it, it is also unable to be deleted. My code works for all other cases I have looked at examples for deleting the head node however it doesn't seem to work in my case. If anyone can help me out it would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class MyLinkedList {

private MyNode head;
private int numberElements;

public MyLinkedList() {
    numberElements = 0;
    head = null;
}

// runtime = \Theta(1)
// if you don't care about ordering
// every time something is inserted it becomes the head node
public void insert(MyCircle m) {
    MyNode temp = new MyNode();
    temp.setData(m);
    temp.setNext(head);
    head = temp;
    numberElements++;
}

// runtime = \Theta(n)
public void remove(int index) {
    if (index >= numberElements || index < 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Index too big or too small!");
    }

    MyNode current = head;
    if (index == numberElements) {
         head = head.getNext();       // I have seen this in other examples to delete the head node. However It does not work for mine. 
    }
    int length = numberElements - index - 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    if (index != 0 && index != numberElements) {
        current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
    } else if (index == 0) {
        current.setNext(null);
    }
    numberElements--;
}

// runtime = \Theta(n)
public void print() {
    // loop through the list until getNext is null
    MyNode current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        System.out.println(current.getData());
        current = current.getNext();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Your implementation on linked list is incorrect. Head is supposed to be the first element added. I don't know if your professor will accept this kind of implementation where the head is the last element inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. A simple - 1 had to be added.

```
MyNode current = head;
if (index == numberElements ** - 1 **) {
     head = head.getNext();       // I have seen this in other examples to delete the head node. However It does not work for mine. 
}
```